# At what point is the ending locked in? I know that unlocking "Rebirth" forces me onto that path

Tags: silent-hill-2

At what point is the ending locked in? I know that unlocking "Rebirth" forces me onto that path.

And Guide Dang It on [TVTropes](https://tvtropes.org/VideoGame/SilentHill2) lists the requirements for the rest...

But is there a way to get off one path onto another, and where / what are the tipping points?

Like, if I'm on "In Water", is there a way to get off it?